Angular DatePicker refuses to display in DD/MM/YYYY
My app set up
import {
  MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS,
  MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS,
  MomentDateAdapter
} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from "@angular/material/core";
import moment from 'moment/min/moment-with-locales';
moment.locale('en-gb')

export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: ['DD/MM/YYYY'],
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: (date: any) => moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY'
  },
};

enableProdMode();
bootstrapApplication(
  AppComponent,
  {
    providers: [
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideAnimations(),
    { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {appearance: 'outline' }},
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB' },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter },
    { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } },
],
  }
).catch((err) =>
  console.error(err),
);

My component HTML
<mat-form-field class="form-date">
  <mat-label>Contract Start Date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="contractStart">
  <mat-hint>DD/MM/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker [startAt]="contractStart.value"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

contractStart.value is an iso-date of the form 'YYYY-MM-DD'
The datepicker still displays the date in the form DD/MM/YYYY?

Any ideas why this may be happening? I've followed all the instructions here: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview
ST
UPDATE
Some bug I cannot understand but this doesn't work
bootstrapApplication(
  AppComponent,
  {
    providers: [
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideAnimations(),
    { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {appearance: 'outline' }},
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB' },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter },
    { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } },
],
  }

However this does, (putting providers in component)
@Component({
  selector: 'app-personal-information-edit',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatDatepickerInput, MatDatepickerToggle, MatDatepicker,
    MatMomentDateModule, MatIcon],
  templateUrl: './personal-information-edit.component.html',
  providers: [
    DatePipe,
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB' },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter },
    { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } },
  ],
  styleUrl: './personal-information-edit.component.scss'
})


export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: ['DD/MM/YYYY'],
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: (date: any) => moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY'
  },
};

The dateInput from parse indicates how the date will be parsed from input.
The dateInput from display indicates how the date will get displayed on the input.
If you want YYYY-MM-DD format, try this config
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: ['YYYY-MM-DD'],
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY'
  },
};

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks, I tried this, but it didn't work : (

I updated my answer ;) without (date: any)=> moment(date).format('.....') Stackblitz

Thanks. I tried, but it didn't work. Your stackblitz won't load for some reason - it says 'Too much recursion'. I'll have another attempt though

Tried chrome. stackblitz worked (didn't on firefox). Your version does work. Can't figure out why mine on jetbrains IDE doesn't. Thank you though!
